# ST_Intersects slow across two tables

Tags: postgis, postgresql, optimization, st-intersects

I have a set of municipality maps, with an ID for each municipality, and a Multipolygon for the geometry. In PostGIS, I've put these data into tables. Table 1 has the municipalities in year 2019 (each row is 1 muni with ID and geometry), and Table 2 has the municipalities in year 2005. Spatial indices for both tables. About 400 rows in each table.

Here are some stats on this data:
All in the same projection: WGS 84

```
NPoints | Avg   | Max    | Min
2019:   | 14378 | 379875 | 9
2005:   | 24675 | 556334 | 5
```

```
Num Geometries | Avg   | Max    | Min
2019:          |  63   | 4402   | 1
2005:          | 131   | 9480   | 1
```

ST_Valid: 4 invalid geometries out of about 400 in each set.

Basically what I want to do is look at the intersection and see how similar the two geographies are across time. So, I wrote the query below.

```
SELECT m1.munid, ST_Intersection(m1.wkb_geometry, m2.wkb_geometry)
INTO intersect_table
FROM m2019 m1
LEFT JOIN m2005 m2 on m1.munid = m2.munid
```

Essentially I join based on the muni IDs (which don't change across time), then create the intersection. But this query basically doesn't finish, I've left it for 30 minutes and I can't imagine it should take longer. Am I being unreasonable or am I going about this incorrectly?

Comment: are all of your geometries valid? and in the same projection?

Comment: `ST_Intersects` is a (*boolean*) spatial relation check operator; **you are looking for `ST_Intersection`** to create a geometry, which should complain about any invalid geometries...but also is not the most straight forward way to measure similarities; at least use `ST_Difference`. Better suited are measures like differences in `ST_Area` and `ST_Perimeter`, or using e.g. `ST_FrechetDistance` on the boundaries. A spatial index is of no use here, a *PRIMARY KEY* or index on `munid` may be (although I doubt PG will bother using it at all for 400 rows each).

Comment: How large are those geometries? Can you add the averages/min/max of `ST_NumGeometries` and `ST_NPoints`? And check for `ST_IsValid`?

Comment: Thank you @IanTurton and @geozelot! I've added stats in the question. Definitely right, I meant ST_Intersection. The munid is primary, but like you said, that doesn't seem so important. Could the few invalid geometries be causing problems? I can exclude those. I will also look at `ST_Differentce, ST_Area, ST_Perimeter, ST_FrechetDistance`

Comment: Why are you using a left join on the tables in conjunction with ST_Intersection?  Won't the join try to run ST_Intersection when m2.wkb_geometry is null?  Will st_intersection then return a null value?  If so, that may cause a problem with Select Into.  See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655490/select-into-variables-when-a-column-is-null  I would try to do an inner join, try just selecting the data, not selecting it into a table, or using create table as select ...

Comment: @omar unfortunately you are looking at a major table/db design issue here: **you have to dump those *MultiPolygons***! To give you an idea what is going on:  *each* geometry in a *MultiPolygon* of `table A` will get *compared against each* geometry in the matching *MultiPolygon* of `table B` -> on average, *for each joined row* you force the DB to compare ~8000 geometries, with ~ 1.8 million operations on vertices (this is a ballpark figure based on your averages, but the magnitude is correct). **x 400**!

Answer (score 0):

So I did a redesign in a way, as suggested by @geozelot. Basically, I processed the data using a cursor, row by row, in Python using sql/geoalchemy, and dumped the result into another table, row by row. In particular, when doing the processing, I processed from least number of geometries to most (see the starred line below). So I had most of my answers within minutes, it's just took a few hours to run with the big geometries. But I was able to have incremental results and examine those while I let the computer process in the background.

Not sure how to achieve this in any kind of straight up SQL query that really does all the processing at once.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine('postgresql://NAME:PASSWORD@localhost/DB_NAME')

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

class Muni2005(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'm2005r'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    munid = Column(Integer)
    name = Column(String)
    wkb_geometry = Column(Geometry(geometry_type='MULTIPOLYGON', srid=4326))
                       
class Muni2019(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'm2019r'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    munid = Column(Integer)
    name = Column(String)
    wkb_geometry = Column(Geometry(geometry_type='MULTIPOLYGON', srid=4326))

class Inters(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'inters'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_2019 = Column(Integer)
    munid = Column(Integer)
    name = Column(String)
    inter = Column(Geometry(srid=4326))
    g2005 = Column(Geometry(srid=4326))
    g2019 = Column(Geometry(srid=4326))


conn = engine.connect()
import time
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import func,text

Inters.__table__.drop(engine)
Inters.__table__.create(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
**munis = session.query(Muni2019).order_by(text("ST_NumGeometries(wkb_geometry)"))**
for muni in munis:
    print muni.name, muni.munid
    match2005 = session.query(Muni2005).filter(Muni2005.munid==muni.munid)
    for muni2005 in match2005:
        i = Inters()
        i.id_2019 = muni.id
        i.munid = muni.munid
        i.name = muni.name
        i.g2005 = muni2005.wkb_geometry
        i.g2019 = muni.wkb_geometry
        i.inter = session.query(func.ST_Intersection(i.g2005, i.g2019))
        session.add(i)
    session.commit()
```